# <li> tree structure traversal not working in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tree

I have a piece of codetree structure in html document I want to traversal using javascript. The codetree (directory tree) is displayed as the following in html:

```
<ol id="start">
    <li>
        <label for="1">..</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="1">
        <ol>
            <li>
                <label for="2">..</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="2">
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <label for="3">..</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="3">
                        <ol>
                            <li>
                                <label for="4">..</label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="4">
                                <ol>
                                    <li>
                                        <label for="5">..</label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="5">
                                        <ol>
                                            <li class="file badfile">
                                            </li>
                                        </ol>
                                    </li>
                                </ol>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label for="6">..</label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="6">
                                <ol>
                                    <li>
                                        <label for="7">..</label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="7">
                                        <ol>
                                            <li class="file">
                                            </li>
                                        </ol>
                                    </li>
                                </ol>
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I want to collapse the directory tree if the "`file`" (on the leave of the tree) is NOT a "`badfile`", else keep the tree expanded. The labels aren't exactly what I have for real code, but the structure is exactly the same. The `<input>` attribute "`checkbox`" determines whether the directory is expanded or collapsed.

Here is what I tried:

```
function collapse(node) {
    if ($(node > 'li').hasClass('file')) {
        if (!$(node > 'li').hasClass('badfile')) {
            $(node > 'li').addClass('hidden');
        }
        return;
    }
    else {
        $(node > 'li').each(function() {
            collapse($(this));
        })
        if (node.children(':visible').length == 0) {
            $(node).prop("checked", false);
        }
        return;
    }
}

collapse($("#start"));
```

The collapse doesn't respond at all, could anyone help me to troubleshoot this recursive function? Thanks!

Update:
I revised to this, it still doesn't work, can anyone take a look?

```
function collapse(node) {
  node.children().each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('file')) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('badfile')) {
        $(this).addClass('hidden');
      }
      return;
    }
    else {
      collapse($(this));
      if (node.children(':visible').length == 0) {
        node.prop('checked', false);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: you can't concatenate an object and a string

Comment: Do you have a proposed solution? I just started programming javascript

Comment: `node.children()` is equivalent to what you are trying to concatenate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) As 'charlietfl' pointed. You can not do `$(node > 'li')` as is not possible either all the content of `$()` is an object or a string. so `$(node).children('li')`

2) I will suggest you to read something about 'DOM Tree' http://www.w3schools.com/ is good to start. Even if **jQuery** will accept your function `.children()` or character `>` will always analize just the first level childs (in depth) so your most-outer `<li>` and nothing else. As objects with class `badfile` is a deep child of `node` you can only perform `.find('li').each()` that will select all matching objects either if direct childs or childs of childs and more...

```js
function collapse(node) 
{
  node.children().each(function() 
  { 
    if ($(this).hasClass('file')) 
 {
      if ($(this).hasClass('badfile')) 
   {
        $(this).addClass('hidden');
      }
      return;
    }
    else 
 {
      collapse($(this));
      if (node.children('ol').children(':visible').length == 0)
   {
        node.children('input').prop('checked', false);
      }
   else
   {
  node.children('input').prop('checked', true);
   }
    }
  });
}

collapse($("#start"));
```

As I told you, check how DOM tree works.

```css
.hidden
{
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 0;
 display: none;
}
```

Comment: you mean node or $(node)? The object i passed in is already $('...')

Comment: Yes, but jQuery ask you to use $() again to give you their functions. As node is now just something similar to a string that contain the element ID.

Comment: the node I pass in is $("#start")

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You are right. It makes no difference as node is allready a istance.

Comment: Done, can you read carefully my answer. I told you there is no sense to do so, as children of node is just your first <li> you need to perform a find to go deeper in the DOM tree.

Comment: I checked your profile. You are building this function out from your previous question. They told you to use children as all <li> where one next to each other in the same object. Not nested one inside the other.

Comment: Did you notice the `collapse($(this));`? That's the recursive call of the function to go deeper into the tree

Comment: Yes, but i missed the logics of the function. If you told me that you can use node without $() so why you use this with $() all the time? Try $(node). Furtermore i dont see the CSS of hidden, but jQuery selector ':visible' is defined:

Comment: Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.

Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout.

Comment: I just implemented your code. Now may i ask you: what is not working? As jQuery do its job, script work, maybe it do not remove exactly what you want due to you are setting 'hidden' to the wrong element.